# Dopesheet - What is the difference between Select methods Border Axis Range and Border select?

Tags: animation, selection-tools, dopesheet

In Dopesheet you have two border select methods. Border Axis Range and Border select. They share the same tooltip, which is made for Border Select. The manual has no info about Border Axis Range neither. And there is also no visible difference by using the tool from what i can see.

So what is the difference between Select Border Axis Range and Border select?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but the answer might be useful to someone:

- *Border Select*: Selects the elements inside of a given rectangle.
- *Border Axis Range*: Selects the elements between the left and right sides of the rectangle, regardless of their vertical position.

Example:
[image: The results of using a given selection rectangle, on a given set of keyframes, using border select and border axis select in blender.]

In other wordes, *Border Axis Range* is a range selection tool, while *Border Select* is a box selection tool.

*Border Axis Range* is useful for armatures with a large number of bones: If you cannot fit all the rows in one window, you can still select over a range without having to scroll up or down.